# Merge two tables in one

Tags: php, mysql

We have two MySQL tables to track our banner stats per day. One table for the views and one for the clicks. Both tables are set up like this:

**Clicks:**

```
banner_id (int 11)
click_date (date)
click_total (int 11)
```

**Views:**

```
banner_id (int 11)
view_date (date)
view_total (int 11)
```

I need to get the stats per month; for this I got this query (for the views):

```
SELECT 
  bv.`view_date`,
  SUM(bv.`view_total`) AS view_total 
FROM
  tarlo.`tarlo_banners_views` bv 
WHERE bv.`banner_id` = 469 
GROUP BY bv.`banner_id` 
ORDER BY bv.`view_date` ASC ;
```

And for the clicks I have a query which looks pretty much the same. In PHP we combine both results by **date** into one array. Now we were wondering if it's possible to combine the results through one MySQL query (instead of 2).

So we need the results like this:

```
Date:       Clicks:   Views:
2013-07-07  556       156833
2013-07-08  726       175683
2013-07-09  356       130588
```

Instead of 2 results sets like these:

```
Date:       Clicks:
2013-07-07  556
2013-07-08  726
2013-07-09  356

Date:       Views:
2013-07-07  156833
2013-07-08  175683
2013-07-09  130588
```

How can we do this?

Comment: You can do this by join. it s faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  bv.`view_date`,
  SUM(bv.`view_total`) AS view_total,
  SUM(bc.`click_total`) AS click_total,
FROM
  tarlo.`tarlo_banners_views` bv, tarlo.`tarlo_banners_clicks` bc
WHERE bv.`banner_id` = 469
AND bc.`banner_id` = bv.`banner_id`
AND bc.`click_date` = bv.`view_date`
GROUP BY bv.`banner_id`
ORDER BY bv.`view_date` ASC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` both table like so:

```
SELECT 
    bv.`view_date`,
    SUM(bv.`view_total_views`) AS view_total_views,
    SUM(bc.`view_total_clicks`) AS view_total_click
FROM
    tarlo.`tarlo_banners_views` bv
JOIN
    tarlo.`tarlo_banners_clicks` bc
WHERE bv.`banner_id` = 469 
GROUP BY bv.`banner_id` 
ORDER BY bv.`view_date` ASC ;
```